# git double change, same upper case and lower case file name

Tags: git

[image]

these two files are the same file, whenever a change is made, it will display as double changes

this happens after I ran  `git config core.ignorecase false`

I am using window 10, git version 2.29.2.windows.2

it is quite annoying, is there any solution for this?

Comment: What operating system are you using and what version of Git?

Comment: You should never (well, hardly ever) *set* `core.ignorecase` to anything yourself. Git sets it based on how your computer behaves. The only time you should change it is if you have changed how your computer behaves.

Comment: I am using window 10, git version 2.29.2.windows.2